# MS Graph API: webUrl to driveItem

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

Our web app allows storing links to OneDrive/SharePoint drive documents.

These links are obtained with OneDrive File Picker UI, `webUrl` field, look like this eg:

`https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/devops2/Shared%20Documents/Company%20Cases/A12345%20-%20case%20name%20-%20RENAMED/case-report.pdf`

or

`https://company-my.sharepoint.com/personal/user_company_onmicrosoft_com/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%7BC52518FD-05B8-428C-BAE7-A3469890493D%7D&file=%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0.xlsx&action=default&mobileredirect=true`

Is it possible to somehow turn this link into drive-id and item-id (driveItem) for further processing with MS Graph API?
(web app has all the tokens/consents already)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the answer:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/shares-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript

1. "Encoding sharing URLs" section (pass `webUrl` from OneDrive File
   Picker)
2. GET request with this encoded string to
   `/shares/{encodedUrl}/driveItem`